# Locally Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let be $f:I\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ and $g:J\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ two locally Lipschitz functions, we define $G:I\times{J}\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $G(x,y)=f(x)\cdot{g(y)}$ , is this a locally lipschitz function?

I think that this is false, but I haven't found any counterexample.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it is true.
Let $[a,b]\subset I$, $[c,d]\subset J$, let $L_f, L_g$ be Lischitz constants for $f$ and $g$ respectively in $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$.
Since $f$ and $g$ are bounded respectively on the compact sets $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ (say by a constant $C$), you have that
$$
\begin{split}
&|f(x_1) g(y_1) - f(x_2) g(y_2)| \leq
|f(x_1) g(y_1) - f(x_2) g(y_1)| +
|f(x_2) g(y_1) - f(x_2) g(y_2)|
\\ & \leq C |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| +
C |g(y_1) - g(y_2)|
\leq C [ L_f |x_1 - x_2| + L_g |y_1 - y_2|]
\\ & \leq K \| (x_1, y_1) - (x_2, y_2)\|,
\quad \forall (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2) \in [a,b]\times[c,d],
\end{split}
$$
with $K = 2 C \max\{L_f, L_g\}$.

Comment: Why are f and g bounded?

Comment: A continuous function is always bounded on a compact set (Weierstrass' theorem).

Comment: But f and g can be no-continous

Comment: A locally Lipschitz function is always continuous.

Comment: Are  you sure? I think that the function $ f:[0,1]\rightarrow{\mathbb{R}}$ such that f(x)=0 if $x\in{[0,1/2[}$  and f(x)=1 if  $x\in{[1/2,1]}$ is not a continuos function and it is globally lipschitz (so it is locally lipschitz))

Comment: This function is not Lipschitz continuous, as you can see considering the difference $|f(1/2 + 1/n) - f(1/2 - 1/n)|$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69646/discussion-between-mathlife-and-rigel).

Comment: This happens with the sum of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @Rigel can u please explain the last step. How did it come like "K||(x1,y1).......||